# Calculate wind speed on aircraft given measurements of speed and heading

Tags: vectors, aircraft

I have X amount of speed measurements of an aircraft, each measurement includes a heading and a forward ground speed.
What I want to do is to calculate the wind speed affecting the craft.

For example:

- Measurement 1: Heading 0 (North), Speed 10 m/s
- Measurement 2: Heading 90 (East), Speed 15 m/s
- Measurement 3: Heading 180 (South), Speed 10 m/s

**Given this, I would assume a wind speed of 5 m/s straight East.**

In the above example it's a perfect solution. But I would also need it to work in the following example:

- Measurement 1: Heading 0 (North), Speed 9 m/s
- Measurement 2: Heading 60 (East-ish), Speed 15 m/s
- Measurement 3: Heading 180 (South), Speed 10 m/s

This assumes measurements at different angles. If traveling in a straight direction, one would have to look at the total direction in 2D space. How would that be calculated?

For example:
An average speed of [100, 5] where the the X component is the velocity straight forward from the aircraft and the Y is 90 degrees to the right. This would assume a wind direction of 5 m/s to the right, but could equally be affecting the craft with 5 m/s to the right and 5 m/s forward. This would only be revealed once the craft is turned around where the velocity would be [95, -5].